# Unable to connect to local SQL Server database using JetBrains products

Tags: sql-server, jetbrains-ide, sql-server-express, datagrip

I'm having troubles trying to connect to a **local** SQL Server database on JetBrains products (DataGrip, PhpStorm...) although I'm able to connect using SQL Server Management Studio.

The server name that I'm using on SSMS looks like this : `Machine-name\SQLEXPRESS`.

I'm using a username and password to connect, but I'm also able to connect using my Windows account on SSMS.

The issue is that when i try to configure the connection on JetBrains products, it fails.

I put :

```
Host : Machine-name
Instance : SQLEXPRESS
user : username
password: password
database: database-name
```

At the end it gives me a url like this :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://Machine-name\SQLEXPRESS;database=database-name
```

But I get an error like this : `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out` stating "*Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connection at the port. Make sure that TCP connection to the port are not blocked by a firewall....*"

I think it has to do with the configuration on these products because I can successfully connect to my database using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Usually, javabased stuff doesn't do instance names. Try ip:port to connect, like: 192.168.10.1:1433 or servername:1433

Comment: @siggemannen I've put the ip address but I still get the same issue unfortunately. The database is stored locally but I've got the "Machine-name\SQLEXPRESS" expression from the config automatically detected by SQL Server Management Studio;

Comment: It probably doen't run on default 1433 port then. Check out in the sql server configuration manager which port it uses

Comment: Quite likely your SQL Server is not listening on TCP (as far as I remember TCP connections are not allowed by default, at least it was in the past) and only uses Shared Memory for example. Check SQL Server config tool (not SSMS, a separate one, check your start menu items as I do not remember the name). Check this one: https://help.dugeo.com/m/Insight/l/438913-troubleshooting-enabling-tcp-ip-in-the-sql-server

Comment: The answer provided by @LazyOne makes sense. Speaking from our experience with MSSQL Server, it's primarily related to disabled tcp/ip connection in the config manager. The native connectors can use the built-in MSSQL protocols to connect to a SQL instance, whereas DataGrip does not.

Answer (score 1):

DataGrip establishes a connection to MS SQL Server via JDBC using TCP/IP. So, MS SQL Server Express Edition should be configured properly:

1. In general, it's a good idea to check either [MS SQL Server is configured to accept TCP/IP connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16#assign-a-tcpip-port-number-to-the-sql-server-database-engine) or operates over [shared memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-sql-server-network-protocol-configuration?view=sql-server-ver16#default-configuration).
2. Moreover, [check your Firewall settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver16) since it could block packets.